How to mint token after close mint in Token extension program
I'm a beginner, and I'm learning the close mint part of the token extension program. I want to understand how to mint an amount of tokens then close mint (not allowed to mint any more tokens)
Thank you so much!

You can create a token like this:
spl-token create-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb

spl-token mint yourmint 100

Then you can disable the mint like so:
spl-token authorize yourMint mint --disable

Find a guide here that also includes on how to add meta data:
https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/how-to-create-a-token
